# Can't set proxy for soapUI correctly

Tags: rest, proxy, soapui

I try to test some API using soapUI but can't ficure out how to set proxy.
When I installing python packages I set proxy in the next way:

```
--proxy=http://domen%5Clogin:password@proxy.city.com:3131
```

But soapUI has different fields like Host, Port, Excludes, Username and Password.
I tried this:

```
Host http://proxy.city.com
Port 3131
Excludes
Username domen%5Clogin
Password password
```

But I get this:

> Error getting response; java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   http://proxy.city.com/

What can be wrong?

P.S. If it is important I'm using Windows 10 and trying to sent GET method to Mattermost server.

Comment: What version of soapUI are you using? Some of the 4.x versions had bugs around this area.

Comment: I'd agree with @craigcaulfield, meanwhile, can you try with the IP address ?

Comment: @craigcaulfield I'm using SoapUI-5.4.0.

Comment: @WilfredClement Ok, I will try it and give you feedback.